# Recruitment: FOSS CRM(-ish)

Tags: open-source, php, mysql, crm

I have to implement a CRM(-ish) system for a recruitment agency.

I say CRM-ish, because I don't need any finical features.

Basically, for candidates, I want to record their technical skills & contact details, while for companies I want to record the skills they need & contact details.

For both, I want to record notes & last contact time.

I also want to be able to add my own data fields.

I would  strongly prefer PHP and MySql.

FOSS, preferably long term stable with a good support base/forums and documentation.

What can you recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some suggestions:

[SuiteCRM](https://suitecrm.com/) is a fork/successor/improvement on the old community version of SugarCRM.

- You can use it for both contacts (candidates) and companies.
- You can record notes/calls etc, and hence can record last contact time.
- You can add fields via its "Studio".
- It is PHP/MySql based, and Open source.
- Since it evolved from SugarCRM, it has it's own community, user/developer documentation, etc.
- It probably has much more than you need. So you may have to hide or disable some of the modules.

The other suggestion is that there are a few drupal-based php/mysql open source options like [Redhen](https://www.drupal.org/project/redhen), [CRM Core](https://www.drupal.org/project/crm_core), etc. There are also a few recruitment based modules/distributions like [Recruiter](https://www.drupal.org/project/recruiter). But usage/stability for the CRM modules, from my experience, is not as solid as SuiteCRM.

Another one to look at is [CiviCRM](https://civicrm.org/). It is known for not-for-profit and civic sectors. It is open source, and integrates with CMS like drupal, wordpress, etc. But can be adapted for your needs too. It is also php/mysql open source, and is widely used.

Comment: Thanks a 1,000,000. Since you seem to know about CRM, could you please take a look at [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/56486/gratis-customer-relationship-management-crm-abstraction-api) ?